# Unable to locate package libdbus-1

Tags: pi-3b+

So, I'm trying to run the following code on my Raspberry Pi 3b+:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libdbus-1{,-dev}
```

And I get the following result:

```
Unable to locate package libdbus-1
```

This is the full picture.

[image: Screenshot of console - Error: Unable to locate package libdbus-1]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I installed `libdbus-1-3` and `libdbus-1-dev` successfully

Comment: @JaromandaX Weird.. Any idea why mine won't? Any way I can resolve this?

Comment: well, you're trying to install `libdbus-1{,-dev}` - have you tried installing `libdbus-1-3` and `libdbus-1-dev` ... or `sudo apt-get install -y libdbus-1{-3,-dev}`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question. What operating system do you use? Is it Raspbian?

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are using **Raspbian** with its default repository I find on my RasPi with Raspbian Buster:

```
rpi ~$ apt list libdbus-1*
Listing... Done
libdbus-1-3/testing,now 1.12.16-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libdbus-1-dev/testing 1.12.16-1 armhf
```

As you can see there is no `libdbus-1` that you try to install and that's exactly what your error message says.